# Apple's Bonjour SDK for Windows

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, bonjour

I am planning to use Apple's Bonjour SDK for Windows in a small .NET application using C#.  This little application will use Bonjour for network discovery.  Currently, I am testing the "Simple Chat Bonjour" sample application that came with Apple's SDK.  After I published that sample, I tried to run the setup on another machine it said Bonjour service is not available.  I checked my original development machine, it had Boujour service installed and started.  And if I stop the service, the sample app will not work.

Question:  Does that mean that any workstation/client machine that will use any application that used Apple's Bonjour needed to have Apple's Bonjour SDK installed?  If this is the case, is there another around this?  (without having to install Bonjour SDK or service on client machine)

Comment: You may also consider the [Mono.Zeroconf](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf) project which is an implementation of the same protocol under the Mono umbrella.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Bonjour for windows as a standalone installer which can be bundled with your application.  See [this](http://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/agreements/bonjour.html#bonjourwin) page for the licence agreement and download [Bonjour for windows here](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html).

Comment: I ended up not using any of Bonjour... But if I did the standalone installer as you suggested is the one.

Comment: What did you use instead?

Comment: Nowadays a typical windows PC at least also runs UPNP discovery and microsofts discovery technology. Often, one application or another installs bonjour in addition to that. I never found the dns-based discovery very attractive, nor liked the idea to "put everything into dns", which basically started with smtp and mx records, which was the first time I thought "oops - what are they doing?"

Answer (score 0):

I recently work on another project that I have decided to go ahead and use Bonjour.  For the completeness of solution:

1. Each Windows machine needed to have the Apple's Bonjour printing for Windows installed.  The link is from [CV's](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999).
2. There is an Apple Bonjour for Windows SDK.  But I found that this third party [wrapper](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/03/bonjour-for-net.html) is way better if you are already familiar with using Bonjour under iOS or OSX.