# advertise self on the network in order to be discovered by other app using Bonjour

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, udp, bonjour

I am planning to put together a small .NET using C# for Windows app.  The app needed to advertise itself on the network so anther app (iOS app) can discover it using Bonjour.  But I do not wish to use Apple's Bonjour SDK for Windows for the reason that I have posted in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735899/apples-bonjour-sdk-for-windows)   .  This Windows app does not need to discover other devices.  It only needed to be discovered.  Can it be done?  If so, sample code or some steps needed to be follow would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mono.Zeroconf](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf) provides a managed API for Bonjour services. It can use either the [Apple Bonjour transport](http://Bonjour/mDNSResponder) or the open-source [Avahi](http://avahi.org/wiki/AboutAvahi).

It is a full abstraction that is independent of provider.

They have an example on how to register services on the main page.

Comment: I ended manually allowing user to enter ip and port... but your suggested option is something I would consider.